# Prototype 'this' does not point to object

Tags: javascript, node.js, this

I have looked at similar questions here on the stack but could not come up with a solution.

My issue is that the following code's `this` does not point to the object in question, instead it points to the `environment` (`window`) in Node.JS.

I'm sure it's something trivial but after about 2 hours of research I have officially given up and it's time to ask for help.

**Code:**

```
var slice = Array.prototype.slice;

function Chain(options, links) {
  if (!(this instanceof Chain)) return new Chain(options, slice.call(arguments));
  return this;
}

Chain.prototype.quicklink = function quicklink(fn) {
  console.log(this);
};


var Chain = require('./chains');
var chain = Chain();
var _ = chain.quicklink;

_('extern_var', 'something', '$callback');
```

**Expected:**
`this` to point to `Chain` object.

**Result:**
`this` points to `environment` or `window` in `Node.JS`

**Prototyping:**
I use JSBin for prototyping. Here is the prototype there. It has essentially the same effect as my Node environment.
http://jsbin.com/OSaHaZAK/1/edit

Comment: Tested it in Chrome, and it seems to work there, strange that Node would give another result? -> http://jsfiddle.net/Q8syd/1/

Comment: @adeneo That's not the same. Look at how the OP is **calling** the function. `var _ = chain.quicklink;` and then `_()`. The context of `this` is lost

Comment: @Ian - Oh, I see now!

Comment: @LeviRoberts Why do you expect `this` to point to the chain instance when you call the `quicklink` function without the `chain` identifier? You're storing a reference to the function in `_`, and then calling that. That's not the same as `chain.quicklink()`

Comment: Read more about the `this` keyword: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: I had assumed that `this` context would be held since `quicklink` belongs to the `Chain` object.

Comment: @LeviRoberts Right, but as the link I posted explains, calling functions isn't the same in JS as it is in other languages. It's just how functions are treated differently

Comment: You are correct. Only worked with `this` a few times. Experience is key.

Comment: @LeviRoberts Yeah of course, that's why you come to StackOverflow :) I definitely would have expected the same behavior as what you're saying, but like you said, experience helps

Comment: @LeviRoberts And as a suggestion, go through MDN's tutorials and use them as a reference when you can. They have one of the better docs for JavaScript, and you can learn a lot there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must maintain the context for `quicklink`:

```
var _ = chain.quicklink.bind(chain);
```

The problem you have is classic:

```
var o = {};
o.f = function () { console.log(this); };
o.f(); //o

var f2 = o.f;
f2(); //window
```

- [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Uamdc/)
- [read about how `this` works on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Comment: That did the trick! I think this is the more elegant solution.

Comment: This is definitely elegant, but almost defeats the purpose of adding a method to the `prototype`. It just causes there to be more code for calling the function. It could be simplified if it was added as a property to the `Chain` constructor instead of its prototype.

Comment: @Ian I don't know what the OP's plan or the code's purpose is, so I don't really want to go into what could be the best way to write his code. IMO there is nothing elegant about the `bind` function, but it does its job. My purpose was to lead the OP to learn more about how `this` works. I wanted to add `call` and `apply` too as an alternative way to fix the context, but I saw that someone already did.

Comment: @kapa Of course, I was just trying to add to the conversation. I wouldn't expect you to have read it, but in the other answer's comments, the OP said they're calling it a few times later and wanted a shorter reference to the function. Do you understand what I say about adding it to the constructor instead of the prototype? The OP could add the following inside of the `Chain` function: `var me = this; me.quicklink = function (fn) {  };` and inside, have a reference to `me` which will always refer to the instance. Sure, that takes away from the gain of using prototype, but its lost with `bind`

Comment: @Ian That is another possible way :). Dropping the `_` shortcut seems to be the most sensible decision to me, but still it is important to learn how context works in JS. Typing less should not really be the most important goal for a programmer, I'd say.

Comment: @kapa Of course, those were my arguments in the comments somewhere else on this page... :)

Comment: To explain further what the code will be used for. I wanted to apply a mechanism to an already built flow-control library. Sure, it's probably not the best way to accomplish this but it is what it is.

https://github.com/bugs181/chains

Comment: There are two primary reasons for the lib. Flow control and reducing spaghetti code.

Answer (score 3):

Call it with `apply` or `call` to set the expected *this* and pass the arguments

```
_.apply(chain, ['extern_var', 'something', '$callback']);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Q8syd/2/)

Comment: The reason for the underscore was to keep the code to a minimum. This does work however kapa's solution is more elegent.

Comment: @LeviRoberts It also makes the code unreadable. Sometimes "longer" code is better and helps prevent problems (like this one).

Comment: Fair enough. I expect this project to be in the hundreds of lines of code though.

Comment: @LeviRoberts - If that's the case you sure are doing this the hard way? How 'bout just using a literal named `_` with all the methods you need inside it, that way you'd keep the scope and the code would be readable as well.

Comment: @LeviRoberts Seriously, your code could be thousands of lines of code, or dozens; you're not going to get any real improvement by reducing the size identifiers. If your reason is to reduce the size of the JS file sent to the browser, look into minification. If your concern is line length, then split up the function call into a declaration of the parameters, and then passing that variable to the function (ends up with 2, shorter lines). If you're trying to optimize, this doesn't help.

Comment: @Ian - And even that wouldn't be an issue, as this code is never sent to the browser ?

Comment: The simple truth is that I'm lazy. I don't want to type out or even have an autocomplete of `chain.quicklink(1, 2, 3)`. It's just personal preference.

Comment: @adeneo Haha crap, you're right. I must've left that possibility in my mind because of the references to `window` in the OP (even though they say they're using node)

Comment: @LeviRoberts - I guess it is, I like literals, as it's easy to find stuff and read, and I write almost everything in Node as literals, but I've noticed that noone else does it, so it's probably just me.

Comment: @adeneo Not just you :).

Comment: @kapa - Well, probably not *just* me, but everytime I read a "how-to" or see a question about Node, all the "good pracice" stuff goes out the window, and globals are everywhere and being passed around in async code like ping-pong balls. I usually wrap things up in literals, and even use just a few variables with different properties that reference middleware etc. that way I can pass chunks of code around in my application with just simple one-liners. On the other hand, some things aren't that much of a concern in Node as in a browser, so I guess it doesn't matter that much ?

Comment: @adeneo I think writing maintainable and readable code matters in Node as much as it does in the browser :).

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
var chain = Chain();
```

do this

```
var chain = new Chain();
```

**new** keyword create new instance.

more info from MDN forum. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new

Comment: It should be noted that I had already tried this with the same result.

Comment: But that function does in fact return `new Chain `?

Comment: it needs to be completelly refactored

Comment: Eugene, care to elaborate?

Comment: I think what adeneo was trying to say is that the `Chain` function itself DOES return a `new Chain` object.

Comment: @LeviRoberts. just pointed out overall idea. I'll cook some refactored code I think insted of yours

Comment: @EugeneP—the OP's constructor will call itself using *new* if that wasn't done in the original call, so suggesting to call it with *new* doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to solve this riddle (to maintain the context).

```
var slice = Array.prototype.slice;

function Chain(options, links) {
   if (!(this instanceof Chain)) return new Chain(options, slice.call(arguments));
   return this;
}

Chain.prototype.quicklink = function quicklink() {
  var args = arguments;
  console.log(args);
};


var chain = Chain();
function _() {
  var args = slice.call(arguments);
  chain.quicklink.apply(chain, args);
}

_('extern_var', 'bob', '$callback');
```